# upload file asyn using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

Hi im developing an web application which contains option for file upload.im doing this thing using jquery and generic handler.

Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(window).load(
            function() {
            $("#<%=FileUploadcom.ClientID %>").fileUpload ({  
                'uploader' : 'scripts/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg' : 'images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText' : 'Browse Files',
                'script' : 'Upload.ashx',
                'folder': 'uploads',
                'fileDesc' : 'Image Files',
                'fileExt' : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'multi' : true,
                'auto': true
            });
           }
        );
     </script>
```

and

```
<div>
           <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadcom" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

In each line near : i am getting error as **expected ';'**.If i replace : with : while executing getting error as **XML Parsing Error: no element found**.
can any one help me to make the above script to work perfect.

my generic handler code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

            string savepath = "";
            string tempPath = "";
            tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPathN"]; 
            savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
            string filename = postedFile.FileName;
            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);

            postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + filename);
            context.Response.Write(tempPath + "/" + filename);
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If i comment the scrit form is opening if i un comment getting following 
error:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("#<%=FileUploadcom.ClientID %>").fileUpload({` opening braces was missing

Comment: Your script has incorrect syntax .``$(window).load(function(){ $.fileUpload({}) });``

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses...Missing brackets ??? let me check

Comment: Hi i have included the missed braces once done that ...if i execute getting error as XML Parsing Error: no element found. can u guys please help me to resolve this

Comment: Is your Handler on a local server?

Comment: yes i'm running in the local server only

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask a question though? If you are already using the file upload control, why bother with the custom script? Also, what is the jQuery plug-in you are using? If you are doing this to get multiple files in the upload the FileUpload control allows multiple file inputs in the 4.5 framework.

Comment: he uses a plugin to upload files without postback.Uploader with Progress Bar is also.

Comment: As Hamix Said i dont want to postback whole page on file upload as well as i need progress bar so only im using jquery.

Comment: Plugin which i'm using is  jquery-1.3.2.min.js
2. jquery.uploadify.js
3. uploader.fla
4. uploader.swf

Answer (score 0):

If the `WebHandler` was not added to the IIS, I do not have permission to access it.
Add WebHandler to IIS, The problem may be resolved.
[How create a handler mapping for an ASP.NET handler in an IIS 7 application running in Integrated mode](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add)